# Token extension Transfer hooks js helper functions not adding additional account

Tags: spl-token, anchor-spl

I am trying to use the js helpers to add additional accounts to transfer hooks. Adding the accounts manually works fine:

```
transferInstruction.keys.push(
      {
        pubkey: program.programId,
        isSigner: false,
        isWritable: false,
      },
      {
        pubkey: extraAccountMetaListPDA,
        isSigner: false,
        isWritable: false,
      },
      {
        pubkey: counterPDA,
        isSigner: false,
        isWritable: true,
      }
    );
```

Using the helper functions does not work:

```
    let transferInstructionWithHelper = await 

createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction( 
      connection,
      sourceTokenAccount,
      mint.publicKey,
      destinationTokenAccount,
      wallet.publicKey,
      amountBigInt,
      decimals,
      [],
      "confirmed",
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
    );
```

Using addExtraAccountMetasForExecute or createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction does not add the additional accounts and the on chain error is :

```
> Program logged: "Error: Unknown"
```

Im using:

```
"@coral-xyz/anchor": "^0.29.0",
"@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.0"
```

Here is my complete code:

```
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { TransferHook } from "../target/types/transfer_hook";
import {
  PublicKey,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
  Keypair,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  ExtensionType,
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
  getMintLen,
  createInitializeMintInstruction,
  createInitializeTransferHookInstruction,
  ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction,
  createMintToInstruction,
  createTransferCheckedInstruction,
  getAssociatedTokenAddressSync,
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  addExtraAccountMetasForExecute,
  createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction
} from "@solana/spl-token";

describe("transfer-hook", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);

  const program = anchor.workspace.TransferHook as Program<TransferHook>;
  const wallet = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;
  const connection = provider.connection;

  // Generate keypair to use as address for the transfer-hook enabled mint
  const mint = new Keypair();
  const decimals = 9;

  // Sender token account address
  const sourceTokenAccount = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    mint.publicKey,
    wallet.publicKey,
    false,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  // Recipient token account address
  const recipient = Keypair.generate();
  const destinationTokenAccount = getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
    mint.publicKey,
    recipient.publicKey,
    false,
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
    ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  // ExtraAccountMetaList address
  // Store extra accounts required by the custom transfer hook instruction
  const [extraAccountMetaListPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("extra-account-metas"), mint.publicKey.toBuffer()],
    program.programId
  );

  const [counterPDA] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
    [Buffer.from("counter")],
    program.programId
  );

  it("Create Mint Account with Transfer Hook Extension", async () => {
    const extensions = [ExtensionType.TransferHook];
    const mintLen = getMintLen(extensions);
    const lamports =
      await provider.connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(mintLen);

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: mint.publicKey,
        space: mintLen,
        lamports: lamports,
        programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
      }),
      createInitializeTransferHookInstruction(
        mint.publicKey,
        wallet.publicKey,
        program.programId, // Transfer Hook Program ID
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      ),
      createInitializeMintInstruction(
        mint.publicKey,
        decimals,
        wallet.publicKey,
        null,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      )
    );

    const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      provider.connection,
      transaction,
      [wallet.payer, mint]
    );
    console.log(`Transaction Signature: ${txSig}`);
  });

  // Create the two token accounts for the transfer-hook enabled mint
  // Fund the sender token account with 100 tokens
  it("Create Token Accounts and Mint Tokens", async () => {
    // 100 tokens
    const amount = 100 * 10 ** decimals;

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        wallet.publicKey,
        sourceTokenAccount,
        wallet.publicKey,
        mint.publicKey,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
      ),
      createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        wallet.publicKey,
        destinationTokenAccount,
        recipient.publicKey,
        mint.publicKey,
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
      ),
      createMintToInstruction(
        mint.publicKey,
        sourceTokenAccount,
        wallet.publicKey,
        amount,
        [],
        TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
      )
    );

    const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [wallet.payer],
      { skipPreflight: true }
    );

    console.log(`Transaction Signature: ${txSig}`);
  });

  // Account to store extra accounts required by the transfer hook instruction
  it("Create ExtraAccountMetaList Account", async () => {
    const initializeExtraAccountMetaListInstruction = await program.methods
      .initializeExtraAccountMetaList()
      .accounts({
        mint: mint.publicKey,
        extraAccountMetaList: extraAccountMetaListPDA,
        counterAccount: counterPDA,
      })
      .instruction();

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      initializeExtraAccountMetaListInstruction
    );

    const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      provider.connection,
      transaction,
      [wallet.payer],
      { skipPreflight: true }
    );
    console.log("Transaction Signature:", txSig);
  });

  it("Transfer Hook with Extra Account Meta", async () => {
    // 1 tokens
    const amount = 1 * 10 ** decimals;
    const amountBigInt = BigInt(amount);

    let transferInstructionWithHelper = await createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction( 
      connection,
      sourceTokenAccount,
      mint.publicKey,
      destinationTokenAccount,
      wallet.publicKey,
      amountBigInt,
      decimals,
      [],
      "confirmed",
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
    );

    console.log("Extra accounts meta: " + extraAccountMetaListPDA);
    console.log("Counter PDa: " + counterPDA);

    console.log("Transfer Instruction: " + JSON.stringify(transferInstructionWithHelper));

    // Does not work 
    /*let transferInstruction = createTransferCheckedInstruction(
      sourceTokenAccount,
      mint.publicKey,
      destinationTokenAccount,
      wallet.publicKey,
      amount,
      decimals,
      [],
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    const addedTransferInstruction = await addExtraAccountMetasForExecute(
      connection, 
      transferInstruction, 
      new PublicKey("DrWbQtYJGtsoRwzKqAbHKHKsCJJfpysudF39GBVFSxub"),
      sourceTokenAccount,
      mint.publicKey,
      destinationTokenAccount,
      wallet.publicKey,
      amount,
      "confirmed");

    console.log("Extra accounts meta: " + extraAccountMetaListPDA);
    console.log("Counter PDa: " + counterPDA);
    console.log("Transfer Instruction: " + JSON.stringify(transferInstruction));*/

    // Adding accounts manually works
    /*transferInstruction.keys.push(
      {
        pubkey: program.programId,
        isSigner: false,
        isWritable: false,
      },
      {
        pubkey: extraAccountMetaListPDA,
        isSigner: false,
        isWritable: false,
      },
      {
        pubkey: counterPDA,
        isSigner: false,
        isWritable: true,
      }
    );*/

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      transferInstructionWithHelper
    );

    const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [wallet.payer],
      { skipPreflight: true }
    );
    console.log("Transfer Signature:", txSig);
  });
});
```

And the program:

```
use anchor_lang::{
prelude::*,
system_program::{create_account, CreateAccount},
};
use anchor_spl::{
    associated_token::AssociatedToken,
    token_interface::{Mint, TokenAccount, TokenInterface},
};
use solana_program::pubkey;
use spl_tlv_account_resolution::{
    account::ExtraAccountMeta, seeds::Seed, state::ExtraAccountMetaList,
};
use spl_transfer_hook_interface::instruction::{ExecuteInstruction, TransferHookInstruction};

declare_id!("DrWbQtYJGtsoRwzKqAbHKHKsCJJfpysudF39GBVFSxub");

pub const VAULT: Pubkey = pubkey!("DrWbQtYJGtsoRwzKqAbHKHKsCJJfpysudF39GBVFSxub"); 

#[error_code]
pub enum MyError {
    #[msg("The amount is too big")]
    AmountTooBig,
}

#[program]
pub mod transfer_hook {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize_extra_account_meta_list(
        ctx: Context<InitializeExtraAccountMetaList>,
    ) -> Result<()> {

        // The `addExtraAccountsToInstruction` JS helper function resolving incorrectly
        let account_metas = vec![
            ExtraAccountMeta::new_with_seeds(
                &[Seed::Literal {
                    bytes: "counter".as_bytes().to_vec(),
                }],
                false, // is_signer
                true,  // is_writable
            )?,
        ];

        // calculate account size
        let account_size = ExtraAccountMetaList::size_of(account_metas.len())? as u64;
        // calculate minimum required lamports
        let lamports = Rent::get()?.minimum_balance(account_size as usize);

        let mint = ctx.accounts.mint.key();
        let signer_seeds: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[&[
            b"extra-account-metas",
            &mint.as_ref(),
            &[ctx.bumps.extra_account_meta_list],
        ]];

        // create ExtraAccountMetaList account
        create_account(
            CpiContext::new(
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
                CreateAccount {
                    from: ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
                    to: ctx.accounts.extra_account_meta_list.to_account_info(),
                },
            )
            .with_signer(signer_seeds),
            lamports,
            account_size,
            ctx.program_id,
        )?;

        // initialize ExtraAccountMetaList account with extra accounts
        ExtraAccountMetaList::init::<ExecuteInstruction>(
            &mut ctx.accounts.extra_account_meta_list.try_borrow_mut_data()?,
            &account_metas,
        )?;

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn transfer_hook(ctx: Context<TransferHook>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {

        if amount > 50 {
            msg!("The amount is too big {0}", amount);
        //    return err!(MyError::AmountTooBig);
        }

        ctx.accounts.counter_account.counter += 1;

        msg!("This token has been transfered {0} times", ctx.accounts.counter_account.counter);
       
        Ok(())
    }

    // fallback instruction handler as workaround to anchor instruction discriminator check
    pub fn fallback<'info>(
        program_id: &Pubkey,
        accounts: &'info [AccountInfo<'info>],
        data: &[u8],
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let instruction = TransferHookInstruction::unpack(data)?;

        // match instruction discriminator to transfer hook interface execute instruction  
        // token2022 program CPIs this instruction on token transfer
        match instruction {
            TransferHookInstruction::Execute { amount } => {
                let amount_bytes = amount.to_le_bytes();

                // invoke custom transfer hook instruction on our program
                __private::__global::transfer_hook(program_id, accounts, &amount_bytes)
            }
            _ => return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData.into()),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct InitializeExtraAccountMetaList<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    payer: Signer<'info>,

    /// CHECK: ExtraAccountMetaList Account, must use these seeds
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"extra-account-metas", mint.key().as_ref()], 
        bump
    )]
    pub extra_account_meta_list: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [b"counter"], 
        bump,
        payer = payer,
        space = 9
    )]
    pub counter_account: Account<'info, CounterAccount>,
    pub token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

// Order of accounts matters for this struct.
// The first 4 accounts are the accounts required for token transfer (source, mint, destination, owner)
// Remaining accounts are the extra accounts required from the ExtraAccountMetaList account
// These accounts are provided via CPI to this program from the token2022 program
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransferHook<'info> {
    #[account(
        token::mint = mint, 
        token::authority = owner,
    )]
    pub source_token: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    pub mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
        token::mint = mint,
    )]
    pub destination_token: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    /// CHECK: source token account owner, can be SystemAccount or PDA owned by another program
    pub owner: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: ExtraAccountMetaList Account,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"extra-account-metas", mint.key().as_ref()], 
        bump
    )]
    pub extra_account_meta_list: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"counter"],
        bump
    )]
    pub counter_account: Account<'info, CounterAccount>,
}

#[account]
pub struct CounterAccount {
    counter: u8,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
The helper function is working fine. Problem was that for the create metas function I did not wait for it to properly confirm before using createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction.
This is because createTransferCheckedWithTransferHookInstruction get the accountInfo of the metas account to find the additional accounts.

So when adding "confirmed" here it is fixed:

```
const txSig = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  provider.connection,
  transaction,
  [wallet.payer],
  { skipPreflight: true, commitment: "confirmed"}
);
```

I also update the code above in case someone wants to use it.